# image upload to file system

Tags: asp.net

how can i upload an image to the file systm?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FileUpload` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx).

For example (modified from the linked MSDN article), if you just want a simple form which uploads a file to a path on the server, you can start with something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void UploadFileAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileStoragePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads");

        if (fileUploader.HasFile)
        {
            fileUploader.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fileStoragePath, fileUploader.FileName));
            outputLabel.Text = string.Format(
                "File Name: {0}<br />File Size: {1}kb<br />Content Type: {2}",
                fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName,
                fileUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength,
                fileUploader.PostedFile.ContentType
            );
        }
        else
            outputLabel.Text = "You have not specified a file.";
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Upload A File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploader" runat="server" /><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="uploadFileAction" runat="server" OnClick="UploadFileAction_Click" Text="Upload File" />&nbsp;<br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="outputLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The `FileUpload` control ends up rendering to a simple `<input type="file" />` (but with more attributes set, of course) on the client, as part of the overall ASP.NET form element management like any other server-side form control.

In your question, you specifically mention uploading an "image."  While this code may get you there, you might also be implicitly asking a second question which is, "How can I ensure that the uploaded file is an image?"  If so, you have a few options outlined very well in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71944/how-do-i-validate-the-file-type-of-a-file-upload) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442907/getting-extension-of-the-file-in-fileupload-control) (which refers to more answers on other questions, it's a popular topic).  As always, server-side validation is necessary even though client-side validation is still recommended for a good UX.  Never implicitly trust the client-side validation, always validate user input on the server as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks for bringing that to my attention.  This was one of my older hit-and-run answers that I never went back and updated.  Fixed.

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive answer! =)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code sample:

Your html:

```
<input type="file" name="Pic_0001">
```

NOTE: the html input control must be located within the form

Now your asp .net code:

```
    'this is your file name at html page
    Dim HtmlFilename As String = "Pic_0001"

    'the place to manipulate all uploaded files
    Dim collection As System.Web.HttpFileCollection
    collection = Page.Request.Files

    'for example, you have selected a picture file named hotdog.jpg in browser
    'this variable will manipulate your hotdog.jpg file
    Dim UploadedFile As System.Web.HttpPostedFile

    'retrieve the reference to your file
    UploadedFile = collection.Item(HtmlFilename)

    'this is the location to save your uploaded file
    Dim WhereToSave As String = "c:\test folder\hotdog.jpg"

    'this is your folder that will contain the uploaded file
    Dim Folderpath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(WhereToSave)

    'now do checking if the folder exists, if not create the folder
    'NOTE: this step is needed to prevent folder not exists error
    If System.IO.Directory.Exists(Folderpath) = False Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Folderpath)
    End If

    'now actually save your file to the server
    UploadedFile.SaveAs(WhereToSave)
```